# SSRS expression with arithmetic problems

Tags: reporting-services

I need sum total of the formula in a cell in SSRS report.
My formula is this: =Fields!CONNECTED_SOURCE_QTY.Value/Fields!CF__STANDARD_ROLL_SIZE.Value
I need a sum of the value that will be output of this sum.

Something like this: SUM(Fields!CONNECTED_SOURCE_QTY.Value/Fields!CF__STANDARD_ROLL_SIZE.Value)
But this is wrong, can anyone please tell me how will it work.

Ex: Out ]out will be  1  4   6
Total I need is 11

Comment: can you show some sample data and desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to calculate the number of rolls based on the Quantity and Roll Size.

If the Roll Size is the same for each and you just want to divide the total QTY by the size.

```
=SUM(Fields!CONNECTED_SOURCE_QTY.Value) / Fields!CF__STANDARD_ROLL_SIZE.Value
```